# What is the difference between working on a machine and doing the same task over ssh?

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, python, c

I have been working at University on a local machine which is on a server that I have access to.

I have some **c** code and am able to carry out parallel runs of the code as expected.

However when I am elsewhere and using ssh I get

```
$ mpirun -np 4 prime.c

/usr/lib/command-not-found: /usr/bin/python3: bad interpreter: Permission denied
```

Right now I am on the University machine with two terminal tabs, one under ssh which gives me the above , same as from home. The other tab is without ssh and works as expected.

```
me@server:~/Desktop/path/to/folder$ mpirun -np 4 prime.c
```

I cant figure it out as I am not running python scripts at all. I do not have root at the University but that is not an issue when I am there.

Any advice would be great.

Comment: What is `mpirun`?

Comment: @choroba Message Passing Interface commands for parallel processing

Comment: The problem is not where you're sitting at, but rather, what machine you are ssh'ing **to**.

Comment: Check if you are connected with the same _username_ and, even more important, if you have the same PATH. (`echo $PATH` on both terminals). When you log to a machine through ssh or on the console your bash can be set to read different initialization files.

Answer (score 0):

> Right now I am on the University machine with two terminal tabs, one under ssh which gives me the above , same as from home. The other tab is without ssh and works as expected.

You could check if it's actually the same machine by running for example `hostname -f` or `hostname -i` in both tabs and comparing the results.

Also, on the university machine run `ssh localhost` and then run your mpi command. I expect it would run fine and demonstrate that it's actually not related to ssh. Just that the machine you were connecting to has a different configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Depending upon your shell configuration, you might not have the same `$PATH` configured when running interactively.  Try logging in via ssh to an interactive shell and `echo $PATH`, then the same thing via a single command line on your client.